# How to store datas in the web without any server?

Tags: android

I have Created one simple Game for Android. The game works well. Now I want to store the High scores of the game in the web, so that all the users of the game can able to see this. But I dont have any website as well as server. How can I save this in the web?

Comment: find somebody who can host your data... =]

Comment: no other way to store the datas?

Comment: Well, you have to communicate with something. You have to have a middle-point somewhere, somehow...

Comment: Try to match your Question with your Question Title to get better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [OpenFeint](http://openfeint.com/). It's a special library for holding scores and achievements, it can be simply integrated in your game, and it's highly popular among players. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at [Swarm](http://swarmconnect.com/leaderboards).  They provide a similar system to OpenFeint (as suggested by Egor), with the advantage of being able to skin/theme everything to match your game :)

Answer (score 0):

I used [Skiller](http://www.skiller-games.com) for my achievements and leader-boards. It works great.
You just define the achievements in the developer's console (on their website) and when an achievement has been achieved, you just call an API to let the Skiller system know.

Hope i helped.